# I want sorting on string which contains numbers and characters

Tags: sorting, alphanumeric

I want sorting on string which contains number and character.
First, it should sort number and then string.
Input :

```
string[] alphanumeric = new string[] 
 {                 
 "0012", "0000","1200", "0002", "9700","AB10", "0IWZ", "XZYA", "0003", "ABCD"          
 };
```

Expected output:

```
0000
0002
0003
0012
0IWZ
1200
9700
AB10
ABCD
ZYYA
```

Comment: What programming language is this? It's likely either C# or Java but I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Arrays.sort method like this:

```
private void print(){
    String[] alphanumeric = new String[]
            {
                    "0012", "0000","1200", "0002", "9700","AB10", "0IWZ", "XZYA", "0003", "ABCD"
            };

    Arrays.sort(alphanumeric);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alphanumeric));
    /* output: [0000, 0002, 0003, 0012, 0IWZ, 1200, 9700, AB10, ABCD, XZYA] */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pablo. It worked perfectly for me.